# How to concatenate two astropy SkyCoord vectors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, astropy

I have loaded in coordinate data from two different star catalogs (in real life, Tycho2 and Hipparcos) and I am trying to create a single table of star positions. One gives positions and proper motion in the J2000.0 epoch, the other in J1991.25 epoch. From the [astropy documentation](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/transforming.html), I should be able to transform one to the other and then concatenate them into a single vector of positions. If I run the following MWE, I get an error saying that the two inputs do not have equivalent frames.

```
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord, concatenate
from astropy.time import Time
import astropy.units as u

tpos = SkyCoord(
    ra=[1, 2, 3, 4] * u.deg,
    dec=[1, 2, 3, 4] * u.deg,
    pm_ra_cosdec=[1e-3, 2e-3, 3e-3, 4e-3] * u.milliarcsecond / u.year,
    pm_dec=[1e-3, 2e-3, 3e-3, 4e-3] * u.milliarcsecond / u.year,
    obstime=Time(2000.0, format='jyear'),
    frame='icrs'
)

spos = SkyCoord(
    ra=[1, 2, 3, 4] * u.deg,
    dec=[1, 2, 3, 4] * u.deg,
    pm_ra_cosdec=[1e-3, 2e-3, 3e-3, 4e-3] * u.milliarcsecond / u.year,
    pm_dec=[1e-3, 2e-3, 3e-3, 4e-3] * u.milliarcsecond / u.year,
    obstime=Time(1991.25, format='jyear'),
    frame='icrs'
).transform_to(tpos)

pos = concatenate([tpos, spos])
```

The error I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-3eecaa4d104b> in <module>
     21 ).transform_to(tpos)
     22 
---> 23 pos = concatenate([tpos, spos])

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\coordinates\funcs.py in concatenate(coords)
    373         if not sc.is_equivalent_frame(scs[0]):
    374             raise ValueError("All inputs must have equivalent frames: "
--> 375                              "{0} != {1}".format(sc, scs[0]))
    376 
    377     # TODO: this can be changed to SkyCoord.from_representation() for a speed

ValueError: All inputs must have equivalent frames: <SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg
    [(1., 1.), (2., 2.), (3., 3.), (4., 4.)]
 (pm_ra_cosdec, pm_dec) in mas / yr
    [(0.001, 0.001), (0.002, 0.002), (0.003, 0.003), (0.004, 0.004)]> != <SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg
    [(1., 1.), (2., 2.), (3., 3.), (4., 4.)]
 (pm_ra_cosdec, pm_dec) in mas / yr
    [(0.001, 0.001), (0.002, 0.002), (0.003, 0.003), (0.004, 0.004)]>
```

and if I try `spos.transform_to(tpos).obstime`, the time remains unchanged `<Time object: scale='utc' format='jyear' value=1991.25>`.

What is the `transform_to` method actually doing? What method/function do I actually need to invoke to put the two into the same frame?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but might help someone else.

I think the question is: how do you account for the change in coordinates due to proper motion between the years 1991 and 2000.

The transform_to() method is primarily for changing from one coordinate system to another.  Both catalogues are based on the ICRS frame in this instance.
Also is no need to account for precession of the Earth's axis during this time as this frame is fixed with reference to distant celestial objects.

You can use the apply_space_motion method to account for the proper motion:

```
spos = SkyCoord(
    ra =45 * u.deg,
    dec = 30 * u.deg,
    distance =100*u.pc,
    pm_ra_cosdec =5 * u.arcsec / u.yr,
    pm_dec = 5* u.arcsec / u.yr,
    obstime = 'J1991.25',
    frame='icrs' )

print('co_ords in 1991   ' , spos.ra, spos.dec)

spos = spos.apply_space_motion(new_obstime = Time(2000.0, format='jyear'))

print( 'co_ords in 2000   ', spos.ra, spos.dec)



>>>  co_ords in 1991    45d00m00s 30d00m00s
     co_ords in 2000    45d00m50.5211s 30d00m43.7445s
```

I have added a distance parameter to the object properties, otherwise it results in warnings in the output.  It does not matter what the distance value is as we are only interested in a 2D solution, however, if you are considering 3D motion then it is obviously important.

I am not sure how accurate you need the positions but I increased the proper motion to 
5 arcseconds a year on each axis to to get significant changes over that period.  Only stars like Barnard's star have proper motions in that sort of range.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will give it a try. Ultimately I don't care much about the tiny motions, I just want everything in a single table. I ended up solving the problem by pulling data from Vizier using astroquery and letting it do the transformation.